# CXF: Schema Validation with XSDs in JAR files and using relative imports

Tags: java, cxf

I'm using CXF to provide WSDL based WebServices.
The CxfServlet is running in an embedded Tomcat and my wsdl and xsd files are located in a JAR that's in the classpath.

The imports in the XSD files are using relative paths, e.g. `./../../some.xsd`

The web services get deployed and are working correctly.

However, if I try to enable schema validation I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [/./../../some.xsd] has been normalized to [null] which is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResource(ApplicationContext.java:529)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResource(ApplicationContextFacade.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletContextResourceResolver.resolve(ServletContextResourceResolver.java:82)
    at org.apache.cxf.resource.DefaultResourceManager.findResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.cxf.resource.DefaultResourceManager.resolveResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.EndpointReferenceUtils$SchemaLSResourceResolver.resolveResource(EndpointReferenceUtils.java:150)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.DOMEntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(DOMEntityResolverWrapper.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1081)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:654)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchema(XSDHandler.java:2058)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1014)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1126)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1126)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1126)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:610)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:569)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:535)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.EndpointReferenceUtils.createSchema(EndpointReferenceUtils.java:622)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.EndpointReferenceUtils.getSchema(EndpointReferenceUtils.java:668)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.setDataReaderValidation(AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.getDataReader(AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.getDataReader(AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
...
```

I debugged the CXF code and had the following findings:

1. The `DefaultResourceManager` has the `ServletContextResourceResolver` as top entry which has been added by the `CXFNonSpringServlet`.
2. The `ServletContextResourceResolver` uses the Catalina `ApplicationContext.getResource(String path)` method which in turn expects the `path` to begin with a `/`. It adds this slash and throws in `StandardRoot.validate()` the above listed exception.
3. This exception passes the `DefaultResourceManager` and gets caught by the `EndpointReferenceUtils.createSchema()` method. I.e. non of the other `ResourceResolver` objects (especially the `ClasspathResolver`) listed in the `DefaultResourceManager` are used to load the XSDs out of the classpath.

How can I achieve to get the XSD validation running?
Is there any way, to change the order of the `ResourceResolver`s?

**Edited**

- The `EndpointReferenceUtils.SchemaLSResourceResolver` class resolves the URL just fine (i.e. `newId` contains the desired URL to the relative XSD file).
  However, it doesn't use it as it does not catch the Exception thrown by the `ResourceManager`.
- I do not want to use absolute paths just as a workaround of the resolver bug. From my point of the the `ServletContextResourceResolver` should return `null` if it cannot resolve the XSDs and should not thrown an exception.

Comment: never use ./.. to refer to your xsds, make a folder (i.e. xsds ) and put all of the xsds in it and refer them by exact name of the file and rebuild , it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

For others who may get stuck on this: I was able to follow @Joem's analysis, took it a step further and managed to obtain a fix for this issue on the CXF side. It should work as of CXF 3.3.3 (not yet released at the time of writing this).

See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8041